# UIPickerView Changing UIButton Title Size

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, nsdateformatter

So I'm making Alarm Clock to test my skills but can't seem to figure this out... What I've got a UIPickerView that gives a user a time that they can select. Once the time is selected the titleLabel on a UIButton is supposed to update with the time they selected and it does, but it shrinks the new time so it's unreadable... Is there something that needs adjusted with the formatting?

Before when my page loads
[image]
Here's my code

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date = [formatter dateFromString:@"15:00"];

    assert(date != nil); // Error converting string to date
    return date;
}
```

After when a user has set a time [image]

Any reason why it might be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this seemed to resolve the issue. 
alarmButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing middle truncation of the button's text, and there are a couple of cures for this. You can either make the button bigger by simply adjusting its frame. Or, you can adjust the text size of the title label:

```
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:myButton.titleLabel.font.fontName size:10.0f]];
```